# How to get content of default nginx configuration file in Docker environment on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx

Does anyone can point me in the right direction

I'm trying to get the content of default nginx conf file, but I can't find it anywhere in the system.

Tried:

```
/usr/local/nginx/conf
/etc/nginx
/usr/local/etc/nginx
```

all patch are not exist

My container is up and running, it shows default nginx successful install page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used the official `nginx` container, the content is located at `etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and it's:

```
root@5b67d1564b45:/# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

But why are you interested in this? Usually what you want to do is to use your own config, not the default one.

Comment: Can you give me hint why I can't locate this file by myself on the path that you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @AndrewK that's why I said *Assuming you used the official nginx container*. Can you add to your question how are you running this nginx container? Which `docker` syntax and/or (if any) compose file are you using?

Comment: I grab the official ngunx latest from the docker hub and just follow the docs on how to install it. I did not customize it with dockerfile or any other way

Comment: @AndrewK `docker run -it nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` this is using the official image and returns the content. Can you double check what are you running?